# C++ Vectors in a Class

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

i am working on a worksheet i have for university and the question asks me to "Allow a user to enter 10 numbers from the keyboard into an array" however we have been told that we need to use classes and vectors for this task. When i run my code i get an error stating: "Expression: Vector subscript out of range"
can anyone help?

Array.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Array
{
private:
    vector<int> lists;
public:
    void fillArray();
    void printForwards();
    void halfandHalf();
    void shiftArrayRight();

    Array();
    Array(vector<int>);
};
```

Array.cpp

```
#include "Array.h"
Array::Array()
{
    lists[10];
}
Array::Array(vector<int> lists)
{
    this->lists = lists;
}
void Array::fillArray()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cin >> lists[i];
    }
}
void Array::printForwards()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << lists[i];
    }
}
```

Source.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Array.h"
using namespace std; 

int main()
{

    Array list1,list2;

    //fill array 1 
    list1.fillArray();
    //fill array 2 
    list2.fillArray();

    // print array 1 
    list1.printForwards();
    //print array 2
    list2.printForwards();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you expect `lists[10];` to do?

Comment: I tried googling the issue, hence why i posted here.

Comment: I thought it would automatically initialize every instance of the class array size to 10 (0-9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lists[10];` is not going to create a vector of size 10.  It is going to try and access the 11th element of an empty vector.  If you wanted to create a vector of size 10 then you can use

```
Array::Array() : lists(std::vector<int>(10, 0)) {}
```

I would also suggest you change

```
Array::Array(vector<int> lists)
{
    this->lists = lists;
}
```

To

```
Array::Array(vector<int> lists) lists(lists) {}
```

You should also change your for loops to use the vector `size()` instead of a hard coded value

```
void Array::fillArray()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lists.size(); i++) // uses size()
    {
        cin >> lists[i];
    }
}
void Array::printForwards()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lists.size(); i++) // uses size()
    {
        cout << lists[i];
    }
}
```

Or if you have C++11 or higher you can use a [ranged based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) like

```
void Array::fillArray()
{
    for (auto& e : lists)
    {
        cin >> e;
    }
}
void Array::printForwards()
{
    for (const auto& e : lists)
    {
        cout << e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually the 11th element.

Comment: @immibis Ah yes.  Fixed.